# Jmeter | Load is not getting generated when reusing Jmeter3.0 scripts in newer Jmeter version 5.x

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We have a JMX test plan that works fine with Jmeter 3.0 version. But when we try to run the same scripts (Nongui mode) in newer Jmeter versions 5.x, the load is not getting generated and I don't see any errors in Jmeter log.

At 1st look, it appears like the values of thread count are not getting picked up in NonGUI Mode from the user.properties file and hence the load is not getting generated. But in GUI mode I can see the values are getting loaded properly. The same scripts works fine in the Jmeter3.0 version.

Platform\OS: Ubuntu 14 and Centos 7

Any help\suggestions would be much appreciated.
Please let me know if any additional information is required!

Console:

[image: Non GUI Mode]

Here is JMX Plan

[image: User defined variables]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Release6 Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Release 4 test scripts reused</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="rampup" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">rampup</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(rampup)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="loops" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">loops</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(loops)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="inputDataFolder" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">inputDataFolder</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(inputDataFolder)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="outputResultsFolder" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">outputResultsFolder</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">~/${__property(outputDataFolder)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="version" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">version</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">1.0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="timesToSearch" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">timesToSearch</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(timesToSearch)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="pagesToBrowse" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">pagesToBrowse</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(pagesToBrowse)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="itemsAddToCart" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">itemsAddToCart</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(itemsAddToCart)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="additionalthinkTime" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">additionalthinkTime</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(additionalthinkTime)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="rampupMultiplier" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">rampupMultiplier</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(rampupMultiplier)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="durationTime" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">durationTime</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__property(durationTime)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="formId" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">formId</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">Report-Graffiti-Form</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="homeThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">homeThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(homeThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="categoryThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">categoryThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(categoryThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="productThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">productThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(productThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="checkoutThreadsRG" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">checkoutThreadsRG</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(checkoutThreadsRG)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="checkoutThreadsRB" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">checkoutThreadsRB</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(checkoutThreadsRB)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="checkoutThreadsSUT" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">checkoutThreadsSUT</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(checkoutThreadsSUT)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="registrationThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">registrationThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(registrationThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="searchThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">searchThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(searchThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="RelationshipThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">RelationshipThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(RelationshipThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="anonymousBillPayThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">anonymousBillPayThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(anonymousBillPayThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="registeredUserBillPayThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">registeredUserBillPayThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(registeredUserBillPayThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="myaccountThreads" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">myaccountThreads</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__javaScript(${__property(threads)}*${__property(myaccountThreads)})}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${server}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">${securePort}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">6</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      </ConfigTestElement>
      <hashTree/>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.controlledByThreadGroup">false</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
          <elementProp name="Accept-Language" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Language</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Keep-Alive" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Keep-Alive</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">115</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip, deflate</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="Accept-Charset" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Charset</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
            <stringProp name="Header.name">Content-Type</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Header.value">application/xml</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </HeaderManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Setup" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="filename">${inputDataFolder}initializationSetup.csv</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="variableNames">server,port,securePort,path</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ignoreFirstLine">false</boolProp>
      </CSVDataSet>
      <hashTree/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you you test plan looks like for me (given I add missing `</hashTree>` and `</jmeterTestPlan>` closing tags)

[image]

As you can see there are no [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) at all so your test plan is not doing anything, either it's incomplete or broken or whatever.

We cannot provide any "help\suggestions" without seeing the full test plan and the full jmeter log (preferably with [debug level on root logger enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)) so I can only recommend:

- inspect your test plan in JMeter 3.0 at the same time looking into [changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) and check if any "Incompatible changes" are applicable
- if you're using any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - make sure that the same plugins are installed in JMeter 5.4.1

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T for responding. I could not attach the full Test Plan due to the text limitation. Here is the test plan - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1REq7I36cwN6RTQCRnZBLkxAmU7QhV4ZP